# Creating 360° panorama using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, panoramas

I'm trying to create 360 panorama using OpenCV. I found Stitcher class and now I try to use it. It is working good with normal panorama like this:
[image: Panorama]

This panorama is created using 22 images. Stitcher class is good in that case. It's not fast but result is acceptable.

I have problem when I try to add ground and sky to it. I know it is very hard to this class to connect all this pictures, because ground and sky pictures are very similar to each other. I made some pictures in my house, with items on the floor and it's still not working so I think outside it's even more complicated for this algoritm.

Do you have any ideas how to do it using OpenCV? Maybe not OpenCV, something other, giving better results? Other languages are acceptable too. I know that there are applications doing this, but I don't want to use them. I'm looking for solution to write this myself (using libraries etc).

Comment: You should take a look at Hugin and its toolchain. I know you said you are looking to do this via an API, but another viable solution would be to call the individual Hugin tools yourself. A custom solution would basically amount to a .bat (or a simple cmd line app) that prepares the inputs and calls the Hugin tools one at a time as appropriate.

Comment: Hey. I just want to know was you able to achieve any thing in this regard. Stitching top and bottom through api.?

Comment: As I remember I had problems with stitching top and bottom through this API. This API was good for cylindrical panoramas, but for spherical it was not good enough and very often there were problems.